# Usar geopy en un dataframe para hallar latitud y longitud

Tags: python, pandas, csv, folium

Tengo un dataframe que contiene nombres de barrios de la ciudad de Medellin,Antioquia.
Necesito conseguir latitud y longitud de cada uno de ellos, debido a que los visualizare con folium.Al menos si no encuentra latitud y longitud para un barrio que lo deje en None que yo luego lo puedo conseguir manualmente.

[image: Dataframe]

Estaba utilizando geopy

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
    from time import sleep
    for neigh in df['Neighbourhood']:
        address = '{},Medellín,Antioquia'.format(neigh)

        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="Medellin")
        location = geolocator.geocode(address)
        latitude = location.latitude
        longitude = location.longitude
        lldata = lldata.append({'Latitude': latitude,'Longitude': longitude}, ignore_index=True)
        sleep(2)
```

pero resultaba en este error

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-89-841a354aa25d> in <module>
          5     geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="Medellin")
          6     location = geolocator.geocode(address)
    ----> 7     latitude = location.latitude
          8     longitude = location.longitude
          9     lldata = lldata.append({'Latitude': latitude,'Longitude': longitude}, ignore_index=True)

    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude'
```

Comment: Lo que te sucede es que ```location``` está vacío. Pero tampoco puedo ayudarte mucho más. Es simpletemente lo que significa ese error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que `geolocator.geocode` retorna `None` si no es capaz de geolocalizar la dirección, basta con usar un condicional que cubra dicha eventualidad:

```
from time import sleep
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



def get_coords(neight):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="Medellin")
    address = f'{neight}, Medellín, Antioquia'
    location = geolocator.geocode(address)
    if location is not None:
        latitude = location.latitude
        longitude = location.longitude
    else:
        latitude = longitude = np.NaN
    sleep(2)
    return pd.Series({"Latitud": latitude, "Longitude": longitude})




df = pd.DataFrame({"Neighbourhood": ("El Guamal",
                                     "Barrio Colombia",
                                     "Villa Carlota",
                                     "Castropol",
                                     "Noexisto"
                                     )})

lldata = pd.concat([df, df.Neighbourhood.apply(get_coords)], axis=1)
```

Resultado:

> ```
> >>> lldata
>
>      Neighbourhood   Latitud  Longitude
> 0        El Guamal  6.343141 -75.710626
> 1  Barrio Colombia  6.227259 -75.571970
> 2    Villa Carlota  6.220299 -75.572237
> 3        Castropol  6.218946 -75.567782
> 4         Noexisto       NaN        NaN
> ```